# Is this Axios Token Management Implementation Secure and Efficient?

Tags: javascript, https, axios

I'm working on a web application where I'm using Axios for making API requests. Token management is crucial for our authentication system. I've implemented token management using Axios interceptors, and I want to ensure it's both secure and efficient.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { logout } from "../stores/actions/authActions";
import store from "../stores";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8080",
});

const refreshAccessToken = async () => {
  try {
    const refresh_token = localStorage.getItem("refresh_token");
    const response = await axiosInstance.get("auth/refresh", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${refresh_token}`,
      },
    });
    const access_token = response.data.access_token;
    const new_refresh_token = response.data.refresh_token;
a
    localStorage.setItem("access_token", access_token);
    localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", new_refresh_token);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      store.dispatch(logout());
      localStorage.clear();
      window.location.href = "/";
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
};

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    const access_token = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
    if (!config.headers.Authorization && access_token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${access_token}`;
    }
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  async (error) => {
    // 401 Unauthorized
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
      originalRequest._retry = true;
      await refreshAccessToken();
      return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default axiosInstance;
```

I was told that when the URL is "auth/refresh" and the HTTP method is GET, I should set the refresh token, and for all other cases, I should set the access token in config.headers.Authorization, but I do not quite understand how to implement such condition. Is is something like this?

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    const url = config.url.toLowerCase();
    const method = config.method.toLowerCase();

    if (url === "auth/refresh" && method === "get") {
      const refresh_token = localStorage.getItem("refresh_token");
      if (refresh_token) {
        config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${refresh_token}`;
      }
    } else {
      const access_token = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
      if (access_token) {
        config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${access_token}`;
      }
    }

    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

I appreciate any insights, feedback, or recommendations from the community regarding the security and efficiency of this Axios token management implementation. Thank you in advance!